# Databricks SQL Connector for Python - configure timeout

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I'm trying to use the new Databricks SQL Connector for Python for running SQL query against databricks as explained [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html#query-data). How can I configure the query timeout using this package?
I don't want to use pyodbc drivers.

Comment: I have the same question.

I am running a flask app that connects to my Databricks workspace using a SQL warehouse, but I am getting timeout errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue where I had not closed Databricks SQL cursor & connection.

After adding

```
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

issue was resolved.